# Split screen panels (horizontal divider)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I'm trying to implement a horizontal resizable divider on a `UIViewController`.
Something like [this sample](https://github.com/tir38/android-adjustable-split-pane) from github (the sample is vertical, but easily adaptable to horizontal, which I already did in an Android app)

I'm pretty sure someone has already done it, but somehow seems in using the wrong keywords in my search and I have come up empty.

The idea is to have a `UIWebKit` on the top portion of the view, and a `UITableViewController` on the bottom, where both can be resized by a divider on the middle that separates them.

Here's a screenshot of the Android app... the black line in the middle is the resizable divider:

[image]

Any pointers will be appreciated!

Comment: You need a divider view draggable in your desired dimension only, and, as it is dragged, you need to update the frames of the two subviews that occupy the rest of the screen. However, note that this is not a common iOS interface. More common is an overlay view whose top can be dragged up and down to resize it.

Comment: @matt thanks, I know what I need, I was looking for something already premade that I can adjust instead of starting from scratch

Comment: @matt been think on your last sentence... I agree is not a common iOS interface. Problem is that the "map" on top can't be dragged (nor it should, coz it's a map and it should "pan" when dragged), and also the table on the bottom takes the drag event to do the scroll... My points is, I don't see how your approach could be implemented intuitively.